# Move a QGraphicsScene inside QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt

I am developping a software to display the result of a simulation.
I am using tiles, and since the map has several millions of tiles, I have decided not to use QGraphics abilities "to draw the entire scene, and only display the visible part" because I read it works well with thousands of tiles, not with millions of tiles.

So instead, I only display the visible part of the map (a few hundreds of tiles). It works very well. I add QGraphicsPixmapItem (=tiles) in a QGraphicsScene, and a QGraphicsView.

**My problem is** : how to scroll the map ?
I want to move the object that contains the map (=the scene), so that all the tiles move at once.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found something usefull : `QGraphicsItemGroup`.
What I do is that I display all the tiles of the map into a `QGraphicsItemGroup`, and when I want to scroll the map, I just call `moveBy()` on the `QGraphicsItemGroup`.

So, I have :
`QGraphicsPixmapItem` (=the tiles)
`QGraphicsItemGroup`  (=the container of the map, that moves when we scroll)
`QGraphicsScene`      (=the scene)
`QGraphicsView`       (=the view)

Hope it helps ;p